# Read Plain Text Document in pandas, only one column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[here is the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsd5w.png)

how can I FIX this, thank you

Comment: Try adding a parameter to read_csv, `sep='\s+'` or `sep='\s\s+'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify that your `csv` file seperator is `whitespace`.
To do so you have to add `sep='\s+'` as this says that the seperator in the file is one or more spaces (Regex expression).

### The better way

You have to specify `delim_whitespace=True` as parametes as it is faster that `regex` I shown you above.

So your code should be like:

```
pd.read_csv("beer_drug_1687_1739.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

And also I see that your first row has the **names of your columns**. So you have to change `header=None` to `header=[0]` to get the names of your columns.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.